# Redirect rules for NGINX

Tags: nginx, redirect, rules

Hi! I want to redirect permantently "https://www.example.com/catalog/" page to my home page "https://www.example.com/" . In the same time pages like "https://www.example.com/catalog/page1/" and similar should not redirected.  Can you please help me, what the rules shall I use in nginx? Thanks, Vadim.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow )
Try this:

```
location = /catalog/ {
    return 301 /;
}
```